# Where can I find "Ascended" items for level 70 legendary crafting?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 3 Reaper of Souls I have gotten 2 new recipes for legendary level 70 items:

- [Reaper's Wraps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps)
- [Pender's Purchase](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/penders-purchase)

I know there are more with the same properties that I describe in this question.

These two require a base item for crafting:

- [Ascended Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ascended-bracers)
- [Ascended Gauntlets](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ascended-gauntlets)

How do I obtain these items?

I looked through the crafting recipes I got and the closest I have are these:

- [Sovereign Ascended Bracers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sovereign-ascended-bracers)
- [Sovereign Ascended Gauntlets](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sovereign-ascended-gloves)

But neither of these produced an item that fit those recipes, they created rare items that was named something else entirely. I thought perhaps that any item named "XXX Ascended Gauntlets" would fit the gauntlets, but then I haven't really been able to find or craft an item that is called that so I'm not entirely sure.

Since the crafting recipes for those Sovereign items require Death's Breath which I'd rather not waste, I'm asking here instead of just crafting X items to see if one of them might have the right name/requirements.

So what will fit those recipes? Do I have to start farming level 70 content for white items for this? Will they drop? Is there somewhere/somehow I can up the ante for this?

---

**Edit:** Scrolling to the bottom of the two webpages linked above for the Sovereign recipes, I can see that they are listed as materials for those recipes I ask about, yet when I crafted an item from each I got items named something else, and that apparently didn't fulfill the criteria for those recipes. Either I messed up (went blind?) or there could be a bug here?

I'll farm a few more Death's Breath and try again.

Comment: AFAIk these "Sovereign Ascended bracers" produce a rare pair of  Ascended bracers. I don't know if these work or not though.

Comment: I tried both sovereign recipes once and got items named something else in both cases, thus my question, but now that I scroll to the bottom of the linked pages they are listed as materials for those recipes. Hmmm...

Comment: Rares do have a random name. That goes for all rares though.

Comment: I know, but when checking the recipes the item I had created did not fit the recipe. I'll check again to be sure though since all evidence point to it should've worked.

Comment: Based on the reddit link by Hex in his comment on his answer rare and magic items don't work.

Comment: fyi rifts seems to be a good place to find these whites.  I ran through one level yesterday with tons of armor piles that constantly dropped white armor pieces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These "Ascended" items are simply level 70 common (white) items. You will have to farm for white drops or find a vendor who sells this particular item.

"Low quality" versions or any Magic/Rare version of the item will not work.

Comment: do you know if superior versions work?

Comment: Superior versions should work according to [this reddit comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/21cnqv/white_items_you_may_want_to_hang_onto_for/cgc9enm).

Answer (score 6):

As of [Patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#blacksmith). White items are no longer needed to craft legendary items.

> Legendary crafted recipes no longer require specific Common armors or
>   weapons and instead now require Common crafting materials

Comment: This patch was released on 5/13/14 (at least on NA servers)

Answer (score 0):

Ascended Items drop on the Memorials on Graveyard in Act V. (Briarthorn Cemetery)

Answer (score 0):

This video shows a good place to farm white items

Comment: Please can you summarize the contents of this video in your answer? We try and avoid link-rot as much as possible.

Comment: Summary: Go to Act V: Battlefields of Eternity. Use normal difficulty and equip all your +movement skills. Just run around, looting armor racks/scrap piles, and getting your Ascended items.

Answer (score 0):

Ascended items drop more commonly from weapon racks, armor racks, and anything else similar to those when you are running around.